# Non repeatable request exception in multipartentity android

Tags: android, http, httpclient, image-uploading, multipart

I am trying to upload an Image File from my app to the server using Multipart approach. As soon as I send the request I am stucking in a trouble called as "Non repeatable request exception". I am new to this approach and have no idea how to deal with this.

Here is my code :-

```
File imageFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/link.jpg");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
            byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
            String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);

            InputStream imageStream;
            JSONObject objResult;
            boolean bSucess = true;
            // Base 64 image string was stored with image object , 
            //String imageBase64 = image.getImageString();
            // This base64 to byte , One can directly read bytes from file from Disk
            String imageDataBytes = img_str.substring( img_str.indexOf(",")+1);
            HttpClient client = null;
            HttpPost post = null;
            HttpResponse response = null;
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

            imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(imageDataBytes.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));   
            try{
                //Forming Json Object 
                JSONObject jsonImageMetdata = new JSONObject();     
                JSONObject objMultipart = new JSONObject();     
                try {

                    objMultipart.put("status", 1+"");
                    objMultipart.put("type", "Photo");  
                    objMultipart.put("filename", "menu.jpg");
                    objMultipart.put("filetype", "image/jpeg");
                    objMultipart.put("user_id", "1");
                    objMultipart.put("auth_id", "1");
                    objMultipart.put("userfile", Base64.decode(imageDataBytes.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                    jsonImageMetdata.put("MultipartImageMetadata", objMultipart);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // converting json data to string
                String strImageMetadata = jsonImageMetdata.toString();
                client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                post = new HttpPost("http://stage.phonethics.in/inorbitapp/place_api/menu_list");
                post.setHeader("X-API-KEY", "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e");
                MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = null;
                try{
                    entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                }
                catch(Exception a){
                    Log.d("name",a.getMessage());
                    throw a;                
                }
                entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);    

                // adding text
                entityBuilder.addTextBody("dummyParameter","Dummy text",ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);             

                // adding Image
                if(imageStream != null){                
                    entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", imageStream,ContentType.create("image/jpeg"),"imagename.jpg");
                }         

                // sending formed json data in form of text
                entityBuilder.addTextBody("descriptions", strImageMetadata, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON) ;
                HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
                post.setEntity(entity);         
                response = client.execute(post);
                httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

Can someone help me to sort out this. Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My team hit this same issue this week.  It turns out that using an `InputStream` for the body is the root cause of the problem.  Since an `InputStream` is not re-readable, the request is marked as "Non repeatable".  You need to use one of the other `addBinaryBody` method signatures such as the one which accepts a `java.io.File`.

Comment: This answer is right on the money! I replaced my `InputStreamBody` implementation with a `FileBody` and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem using a class of JetS3t Amazon toolkit, his name is `RepeatableInputStream`. In your case import this in your dependencies. In my project I use Ivy. I show you two mode.

Maven:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>net.java.dev.jets3t</groupId>
 <artifactId>jets3t</artifactId>
 <version>0.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Ivy:

```
<dependency org="net.java.dev.jets3t" name="jets3t" rev="0.7.2"/>
```

After use this class in your imageStream for wrap his as repeatable.

```
// adding Image
       if(imageStream != null){
         RepeatableInputStream imageStreamRepeatable = new RepeatableInputStream(imageStream,imageDataBytes.getBytes());

         entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", imageStreamRepeatable,ContentType.create("image/jpeg"),"imagename.jpg");
       }
```